# Nuget Config - repository path - multiple locations

Tags: nuget-package

I have a requirement where I need nuget packages installed based on the TFS branch I am working at that time. I edited nuget.config and added the key "repositoryPath" with value "..\Solution1\DEV\Source\Packages". However, this path should change to "..\Solution1\MAIN\Source\Packages" when I am working on MAIN branch of TFS.

So, I want the path referred to something like "..\Solution1\*\Source\Packages" so that it can be any of DEV/MAIN/RELEASE tfs branches.

Is it possible to use any regex as shown above? Or, is there any workaround for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No regex expression is possible for this key. It only accepts relative or absolute paths.

If you are using nuget.exe for your NuGet operations, you can use the [-ConfigFile parameter](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file) to pass in a config file per branch. You can imagine having separate config files per branch and based on the current branch you can use a different config file with the right repository path.

Update: Based on OP's comments, this is not viable solution. In this case, the only option I can think about is writing up a script that can that can change the the path based on the branch for the config file.

Comment: No, I cannot have different config file per branch. I need a common solution, so it should not show as a difference during merging code.